The preview always crashes when I try to save an object
I'm new here in the forum, and I'm currently struggling with my first project using the Swift programming language. So don't be surprised if the code quality is poor. I'm just trying to get my project to work somehow. The problem I'm encountering is that the preview always crashes when you click on "Save Recipe". I suspect that the issue lies with the "amount" and "ingredient" arrays. When I run the app in the simulator, saving works normally.
I'm sorry for just posting the long code here, but maybe the error lies elsewhere.
Here's the code for my view:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct NewRecipeView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Query(sort: \Recipe.title) var recipes: [Recipe]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @State private var recipeTitle: String = ""
    @State private var amount: [String] = [""]
    @State private var ingredient: [String] = [""]
    @State private var steps: [String] = ["Schritt 1:"]
    @State private var showRecipeOverview = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Name des Rezeptes")) {
                    TextField("Gib einen Namen ein", text: $recipeTitle)
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Zutaten")) {
                    ForEach(amount.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Menge", text: Binding(
                                get: { self.amount[index] },
                                set: { self.amount[index] = $0 }
                            ))
                            .frame(width: 80)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            
                            TextField("Zutat", text: Binding(
                                get: { self.ingredient[index] },
                                set: { self.ingredient[index] = $0 }
                            ))
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: addIngredient) {
                        Text("Weitere Zutat")
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Schritte")) {
                    ForEach(steps.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                            TextEditor(text: Binding(
                                get: { self.steps[index] },
                                set: { self.steps[index] = $0 }
                            ))
                            .frame(height: 150)
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: addStep) {
                        Text("Weiteren Schritt hinzufügen")
                    }
                }
                Button(action: saveRecipe) {
                    Text("Rezept speichern")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                }
                .padding()
                .sheet(isPresented: $showRecipeOverview) {
                    RecipeOverview()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Neues Rezept")
        }
    }
    
    func addIngredient() {
        ingredient.append("")
        amount.append("")
    }
    
    func addStep() {
        steps.append("Schritt \(steps.count + 1):")
    }
    
    
    func saveRecipe() {
        print("Amount: \(amount)")
        print("Ingredients: \(ingredient)")
        let newRecipe = Recipe(title: recipeTitle, amount:amount, ingredients: ingredient, steps: steps)
         modelContext.insert(newRecipe)
         isPresented = false
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    NewRecipeView(isPresented: .constant(false))
        .modelContainer(for: Recipe.self)
}

This is my Model, it is located in another file:
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Recipe {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var amount: [String]
    var ingredients: [String]
    var steps: [String]
    
    init(title: String, amount: [String], ingredients: [String], steps: [String]) {
        self.title = title
        self.amount = amount
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.steps = steps
    }
}

I have already printed out the values of the arrays for the amount and the ingredient. They seem to always match up, even if, for example, no entry is made in the amount.
This is an example:
Amount: ["5oz", "5", ""]
Ingredients: ["Cheese", "Burger", ""]

Initially, I had a slightly different approach in the model. I stored the ingredient and the amount together, so there was only one array for that. That worked in the preview. However, later I changed it so that they should be stored separately. Since then, saving in the preview unfortunately no longer works. I'm not sure what else I should really change and appreciate your advice.

Does it crash when you run the app?

@JoakimDanielson no it doesn't crash, when I run the app

You need to create the container in the preview when using SwiftData. Look at this example

This is likely the crash ForEach(amount.indices, id: \.self) { index in you can't use ForEach like a for loop you need to give it the model data and a valid id param which is the name of your identifier property, e.g. id: \.uniqueIdentifier. You'll need a model type for your amounts.

If you are on Xcode 15.3 or earlier it might be a duplicate of this question

Thanks guys, you fixed my problems. I complet
